# PMF or PDF given a CDF?

Tags: probability-distributions, numerical-methods

I have two vectors $\{ x_0, ... , x_n \}$ and $\{y_0=0, y_1, ... , y_{n-1}, y_n = 1 \}$ that numerically represent a CDF $y=F(x)$. The $x$'s are not evenly spaced. I want a graphical display of this distribution, so I was wondering if I should derive a PDF or a PMF.

1. Derive PDF using a finite difference method, i.e. approximate $F'(x)$
2. Derive PMF by first transforming the $x$ vector into an evenly spaced one and compute $F(x_i) - F(x_{i-1})$

Which is closer to an actual distribution? Or should I just opt for plotting CDFs?

** Kernel density not an option, because the CDF was not derived out of observed values. I just have a numerical function.

Comment: Why would plotting $(x_i,y_i)$ for $i \in [0,n]$ not meet your needs?  You seem to be describing a piecewise constant function with steps at the $x_i$.

Comment: Is the set of outcomes discrete or continuous? If discrete, plotting the PMF makes sense, but if continuous perhaps you could draw a cubic spline through the data and plot its derivative.